# Relative import error when importing from different package

Tags: python, relative-import

My project structure looks like this -

```
<project_name>

--Makefile
--src
  -- __init__.py
  -- utils
     -- __init__.py
     -- general_imports.py
        -- variable named X
  -- modelling
     -- train.py
```

My train.py module looks like this -

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,'../../src/')

from utils.general_imports import *


print("Value of X is ",X)
```

Now, this works fine if I run the code from the directory **train.py** is present in, but I don't want that. I want to make a recipe so it can run from the root directory level, something like this -

```
make train
```

- **Sample Makefile -**

  ```
  train:

   python src/modelling/train.py
  ```

Please note Makefile is in project root directory.

When I am trying to run my **train.py** from root level like this - `python src/modelling/train.py`, it gives me error - **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src/modelling/train'**.

To overcome this, I tried to edit the path like this -- `sys.path.insert(0,'../../../<project_name>')` and also adding empty `__init__.py` on root level too, but this doesnt seem to work either.

Can anyone please help? Also, please suggest any better way to achieve this.

P.S: I dont want to go by way to add/modify PYTHONPATH if it could be possible.

Comment: You should not use a relative path to add to "sys.path" because it may not be relative to the module in which it was used but to the current working directory (which can be anywhere).

Comment: @MichaelButscher When I run python src/moelling/train.py, sys.path.insert will try to find '../../src' path from there? Like go two level up from <root_directory> and look for 'src', which it never will be able to find as it doesn't exist? And because it never was added to path, module import fails, right ?

Comment: Right. In the described case the current working directory is `<project_name>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the sys.path hack and the `__init__.py` from the <project_name> then run your script from <project_name> as:

```
python -m src.modelling.train
```

This is the correct way of running a script (from the parent dir of the root package which is src in your case). Imports are meant to work in this way but not when running the script from its package which you should avoid as you do

Comment: Works great !!! can you add a bit more description like why added -m and why used dot operator instead of slash / ?

Comment: @PankajMishra: The `-m` switch runs the _module_ specified by its full _module name_ - so the dots here are not operators (hey no operators in the command line :) are the module name inside the package - this syntax which is the recommended one tells python that the module is part of the _package_ `src.modelling` and instructs python to scan for. subpackages the working dir (<project name>) hence all imports work!